# Bootstraps Nav Links Not Working on iOS

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, magento

I'm tearing out what hair I have left over this... on http://www.scribblersteeroom.co.uk the collapsible navbar works fine if you resize a desktop browser but open it up on an iphone and the links just don't want to be pressed.

I've been playing with z-indexes and display types in css and used the role and target attributes to see if that did anything but no joy.

Comment: there is a like a million javascript errors

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, I can't see them in the console...